# Did Walt know the neo-nazis would kill him and if so, what was the reason?

Tags: breaking-bad

If the reason is really obvious, then the neo-nazis would not have let him in the gate -- they must have thought that Walt thought they might do business.

So then, what was the motivation of the frankly absurdly generous Uncle Jack, who had not only done everything Walt and he had agreed to, dating back to the synched murders of the poor men on the list, up to almost killing Jesse? He also essentially gave Walt a fortune -- I can't think of any person I know of who was have done something so, let's say, both generous and fair.

The only thing I can think of is Lydia might have convinced them, or the nazis independently  thought of the fact that by killing Walt, they eliminated the only potential competition for their high-grade meth. But that does not seem very realistic. He was sick, he had no organization or physical plant for making meth as the nazis did.

If Walt was a threat because he might well blab to the DEA, then a swell time to have killed him would have been when Hank and Gomez were killed. But no, Jack shook his hand and let him go -- basically, Jack *likes* Walt. I doubt that Lydia has the pull with Jack, who listens to no one, to have Walt killed.

Of course, Jack and the nazis might have discussed things amongst themselves (and Todd's line, You should not have come here, Mr. White, indicates that there had been some discussion) since the desert and said, You know, we really should have killed Walt then and there. Perhaps that's the best explanation: The nazis just changed their minds or, more specifically, Jack, head nazi, did.

The risk to the nazis by not killing Walt right after they had killed Hank was at its peak then.

On the other hand, perhaps they were making so much *clean* money via Lydia (never explained how she transmitted money to the nazis from Madrigal but I assume she did) that she really was influential. They may have discovered that the barrels of money were no more useful to them than they were to Walt or Skyler -- every drug dealer finds this out: a bunch of illegal cash, in the USA, is nearly useless and it often gets moldy or is eaten by rats long before any significant fraction of it can be spent.

Comment: I urge to read the enormous amount of analysis on this series. BB and BCS have always had massive amounts of articles written about them, tons of in-depth recaps with plenty of analysis and tons of interviews with the makers and actors. Doing so is a far more valuable way to spend your time instead of coming here and asking people to explain very obvious plot points.

Comment: @BCdotWEB: I see no question here which deals with whether Walt expected to be killed and as I explain, this could not be obvious or the nazis would not have allowed him inside. I certainly googled this and the best I saw is, maybe Lydia wanted him dead or maybe the nazis saw him as a threat because he was a wanted man. But he already was a wanted man when he was in the desert. That's when they let him go and gave him 10 mill as I already explained. So I think there is a better answer than what I have found, thanks for your input.

Comment: He wanted to end all this, including his life, but in particular kill these psychos. If you didn't get why they wouldn't kill him in the desert stand-off, but now they would, then maybe watch an easier series. Why? Because that's a normal way to get better in understanding works.

Answer (score 3):

Jack killed Walt's wife's sister's husband.

Jack **took** all of Walt's money except one barrel.

Maybe he left him alive in the desert because of his stature as Hiesenburg or because they had done business together previously and Jack thought of him as a practical criminal who wouldn't be caught up in seeking revenge. But if Walt is back, it's obvious he has come for his money and the murder of his brother-in-law.

Comment: and maybe they played along because it easiest to have walt come to them -- how would they find him in that case? -- and walt knew this -- he wanted them all together in the clubhouse.